# 配列と辞書の宣言方法について

Tags: swift

これらの宣言って同じという認識で合ってますか？

配列

```
var arr = [String]()
var arr = Array<String>()
```

辞書

```
var dic = [String: Int]()
var dic = Dictionary<String, Int>()
```

もし動作などが違っていれば教えて下さい。
また参考になるURL教えて頂けるとありがたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

前者の方が短縮形で、機能としては同じになります。

公式ドキュメントの、The Swift Programming Languageの[Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)に説明があります。短縮形の方が好まれるという記載があります。